# React-native-cli builds failing after installing a package, gradle proxy issue?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-cli

I am attempting to install `react-native-ble-manager` into my native (android focused) application.

After `npm install --save react-native-ble-manager` and running `react-native link`, I get outputs telling me that there was a successful link as expected.

However when I go to build (`react-native run-android --port=5714`), the build fails with the following error:

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-ble-manager'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-ble-manager:classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
>              Required by:
>                  direct_analytics:react-native-ble-manager:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I'm relatively new to react native, so during setup I followed Facebook's ["Building Projects with Native Code" instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) exactly (for windows/android). I should mention that I did the setup for an emulator but I am currently working with a physical device. For the setup of the physical device, I manually downloaded and installed [Google's USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)

I followed `react-native-ble-manager`'s [instructions](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) when installing. Something to note was that my `minSdkVersion` was originally 16.

Before this is marked as a duplicate, I've been searching on SO and GitHub for the past two days finding no answer. Could this be because I'm behind a proxy? The `Connection timed out` leads me to believe so. I've configured npm/node to work behind one, but does gradle need to be? The app builds, compiles, and runs before I try and add `react-native-ble-manager`.

Below is a screenshot of my environment information:[image: environment information]

Also: `react-native-cli: 2.0.1`.

Update: I did nothing but rerun `react-native run-android --port=5714` over and over getting different errors each time until the build succeeded and the app was deployed to the android device. This is frustratingly unstable.

Comment: number one make sure you are connected to internet while building for android because! it requires Gradle Wrappers to be built !!if you don't have already done any native project for android studio which automatically does that for you!

Comment: for now if you are using react native on macOS I will recommend install gradle using Brew  and then try to build the project after that

Comment: @Rizwanatta I am connected to the internet, and the post states that I am on a windows machine.